# Laravel - Use translations in Javascript / React Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, laravel

I currently have a problem with being able to use translations directly in a React component without passing all translations to the component via blade per data attribute. I have found many solutions, but they were all based on Vue.JS.

My translations are in a PHP array, not in a JSON object. Via blade I can get to the individual translations without problems via {{__(...)}}

But how can I get all translations and put them into a javascript variable?

Is there a solution to get translations in a React component without working with data attributes?

Thanks for the help

Comment: You can get the PHP array via an `$array = include resource_path('lang/<language>/filename.php')` and encode the array in a JS variable in the view. Not ideal I guess but it probably works

Comment: So i have to do this in every php file and transfer this to the frontend? I will only do this once

Comment: In every php file i mean, in every controller

Comment: I would use a [view composer](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/views#view-composers) and associate it with the base layout view and put the data in that one.